# How to print data from Android Tablet to a Bluetooth printer

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am developing an application for Android Tablet,now in my application if i select print option then data should be print in the Bluetooth printer.to achieve this first i want to know how to recognize nearest Bluetooth devices and also how to print data in a Bluetooth printer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at any of the [Android Bluetooth Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html)?

Comment: yaa i checked that but need to know how to print in bluetooth printer

Comment: some printers have their own library for android like woosim. I have a sample of pocket woosim printer for android. Is it suitable for you?

Comment: yaa, can u provide some sample for woosim priter thing

Answer (score 0):

Star Micronics has an SDK for Android printing via Bluetooth (as well as ethernet and USB). You can download it here: http://www.starmicronics.com/support/SDKDocumentation.aspx.

At this point in time, the Android OS doesn't support native printing over Bluetooth.

In my experience, it's best to use an API and not an external application. The biggest reason is you get total control over printer behavior. It's easy too if the API is built intelligently. Using an external app is limiting because you can't customize your print outs the way you want to.

The Star SDK I linked you to has a really nice sample app that lets you test and customize a lot of printer functions to see them in action. Each function is documented in the source code. The commands and their parameters are also available in the app itself as a quick on screen reference which is convenient. On top of all that, it's well documented.

If you choose this way, you can send plain text to the printer along with commands. The API handles converting the data into what the printer can understand.